# Mutual information of shared state is larger than expectation values

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, projection-operator, mutual-information

Im trying to prove the following identity for a special case:

Alice and Bob share the Bell state
\begin{align*}
    |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).
\end{align*}
Consider the pair of observables
\begin{align*}
    A = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}
        \end{pmatrix}
    , \qquad B =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3}
        \end{pmatrix}
    .
\end{align*}

Show the mutual information between Alice and Bob is larger than $(\langle\psi | A \otimes B| \psi\rangle - \langle\psi |A|\psi \rangle \langle\psi |B|\psi \rangle)^2 $

I've make progress in obtaining the values for the mutual information using the following:
$I(\rho_A:\rho_B) = S(\rho_A) +S(\rho_B) - S(\rho_{AB}) = 1 + 1 - 0 = 2.$

I would like to compute the expectation but I'm facing a problem in the case of $\langle\psi |A|\psi \rangle$ since the size of matrices in this multiplication do not match. namely, $\langle\psi|$ is of size $1\times 4$ and $|\psi \rangle$ is of size $4\times 1$ and the matrix $A$ is $2 \times 2$.
I'm very new to the subject and I would greatly appreciate if I could have some guidance on how the computations for this expectation would be carried out.

additionally, I have computed the $\langle\psi | A \otimes B| \psi\rangle$ by first computing the tensor product of the two matrices $A,B$ and then taken the multiplication with the Bra and Ket of the state respectively deducing
$$\langle\psi | A \otimes B| \psi\rangle = \frac{7}{12}\,.$$

I would appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: I believe the statement is asking you to find $$\bigg(\langle\psi | A \otimes B| \psi\rangle - \langle\psi |A \otimes I |\psi \rangle \langle\psi |I \otimes B|\psi \rangle\bigg)^2 $$

Comment: this seems to ask about an inequality between quantum mutual information and covariance with respect to a specific pair of observables. Out of curiosity, what's the context here?